# Change the data source of a pivot table with xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am currently using the xlwings package to manipulate an excel file. So far, this package is fantastic, but I do not find a lot of specific documentation on how to modify a pivot table. My main question is how can I change the data source for a specific pivot table?

I think this is a general question so I won't provide any kind of code or excel file.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: this documentation here might be useful: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html

Comment: I feel like I read everything on this website and couldn't find my answer. If you have a specific page that I missed, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, a friend of mine found this website with an answer https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_39906906/article/details/111374735

but since it's in Chinese, I will post the necessary code below.

I don't understand everything about this answer. The `win32c` object is unknown to me and therefore, I am not comfortable in explaining everything.

```
import xlwings as xw
import win32com.client as win32
win32c = win32.constants

# open you excel workbook
wb = xw.Book('excel.xlsx')
# select sheet containing the pivot table
sheet_with_pivot_table = wb.sheets['sheet_pivot_table']

# Write the data range as written in the excel app
data_range = 'sheet_with_data!$A$1:$D$4'

# get the pivot table
pivot_table = sheet_with_pivot_table.api.PivotTables('pivot_table_name')
# This applies the new data
pivot_table.ChangePivotCache(wb.api.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=win32c.xlDatabase, SourceData=data_range, Version=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion12))
```

Hopefully, this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

See in this example, with the `pivotname` that you can change.

```
import xlwings as xw
app_excel = xw.App(visible = False)
wbook = xw.Book( 'Excelfile.xlsx' )
wbook.sheets['datatab'].select()
wbook.api.ActiveSheet.PivotTables('pivotname').PivotCache().refresh()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This only refreshes my table and not the data source. I would like to refer to another tab with a data range in mind.